# Equivallent for $_SERVER['argv'] when using $_POST?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a `$_POST` equivallent for `$_SERVER['argv']`, which only works with `$_GET`.

This is because my ajaxscript recently changed from `$_GET` to `$_POST` due to IE7 issues but the query passed into the ajaxfunction is quite long.

So if there is a simple alternative rather than to reconstruct the `$_GET` string from a `$_POST` array that would be nice :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can read the raw POST body like so

```
$postBody = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
```

Comment: People like you should earn more badges ;) Wonderful tip! I never heard of this before, Thankyou:) +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way I can find to get the actual POST string, but it's pretty easy to construct it.

```
$poststring = http_build_query($_POST);
```

Comment: Thanks I came accros this function too but it reforms some parts of my data... +1 for you reply!